# Formato de las horas en chart.js

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, chart.js

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un gráfico para un ERP, en el cual se muestran a los largo de los días la hora a la que han entrado los empleados. aparentemente me esta fallando el formato de la hora y muestra el gráfico en blanco, en la base de datos la hora se guarda en formato texto ("08:15") y no consigo que google charts entienda el formato. Aquí os dejo el código:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12">
 <canvas id="myChart" height="400"></canvas>
  <script>
   <?php
    $sqlx=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM g_tareas where Usuario='empleadoX'");
    $sqly=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM g_tareas where Usuario='empleadoX'");
   ?>
   var ctx=document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
   var myChart=new Chart(ctx,{
    type:"line",
    data:{
     labels:[
      <?php 
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlx)){
        $dia= date("Y-m-d",strtotime( $row["Dia"]));
        echo "'".$dia."', "; /*Imprimo los dias en los que ha trabado (la línea de tiempo inferior)*/
       }
      ?>
     ],
     datasets:[{
      label:'Historico horas entrada y salida',
      data:[
       <?php 
        while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($sqly)){
         $comienzo= explode(":",$row2["Comienzo"]);
         $hora=$comienzo[0];
         $minuto=$comienzo[1];
         $entrada = date("H:i",strtotime("$hora:$minuto"));/*doy formato de hora a las horas de inicio de jornada*/
         echo "'".$entrada ."',";/*si las imprimo como texto deja el grafico en blanco*/
         echo $entrada.",";/*y si las imprimo como hora no aparece el grafico*/
        }
       ?>
      ],
     }]
    }
   });
  </script>
</div>
```

Actualización:
He modificado el código en base a la primera respuesta que he recibido con un enlace a una respuesta anterior creo que estoy cerca pero sigue sin funcionar:

```html
<canvas id="myChart" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
    <?php
        $sqlx=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM g_tareas where Usuario='empleadoX'");
    ?>
    var ctx=document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var result = [
        <?php
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlx)){
                $dia= date("Y-m-d",strtotime( $row["Dia"]));
                $entrada = date("H:i",strtotime($row2["Comienzo"]));
                echo "{ x:'".$dia."', y:".$entrada."},";
            }
        ?>
    ];
    var labels = result.map(e => moment(e.x, 'H:i'));
    var data = result.map(e => +e.y);
    var myChart=new Chart(ctx,{
        type:"line",
        data:{
            labels:labels,
            datasets:[{
                label:'Historico horas entrada y salida',
                data:data,
                bordeWidth:1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'hour',
                        displayFormats: {
                            hour: 'H:i'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas indicar que el `eje y` es una medida de tiempo, esto se hace cambiando las escalas con `options`, para ello añade después de data

```
,
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
               unit: 'hour',
               displayFormats: {
                  hour: 'HH:mm'
               }
            }
         }]
      },
   }
```

Adaptado de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022879/5675636).

Por otro lado, esta parte del código

```
$comienzo= explode(":",$row2["Comienzo"]);
 $hora=$comienzo[0];
 $minuto=$comienzo[1];
 $entrada = date("H:i",strtotime("$hora:$minuto"));
```

se puede reducir a

```
$entrada = date("H:i",strtotime($row2["Comienzo"]));
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta pero sigue sin funcionar